# How To Check Firestore Collection Field with Flutter For Web?

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, flutter-web

I using developing a web app with Flutter and using Firestore as a backend. When the user logs in they must also log into there company by:

- Selected Company From Dropdown list streamed from Firestore (Working)
- Entering The Company Pin - which is checked against the Pin stored in the collection (Not Working)
  -Then press a raised button to check credentials

If the pin is correct, the user should be navigated to HomeScreen(), otherwise, an error should pop up.

Below is the getCompanyPin() method (The doc id is also the company name):

```
  Future<String> getCompanyPin(String companyName) async {
    String pin;
    await store
        .collection('companies') 
        .doc(companyName)
        .get()
        .then((val) {
          pin = val.data()['Company Pin'];  
    });

    return pin;
  }
```

Below is the method which calls the getCompanyPin() and then checks if the pin is correct

```
  void checkPin(newPin, pin) {
    if (newPin == pin) {
      Navigator.push(
        context,
        MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => HomeScreen()),
      );
    } else {
      //error;
    }
  }
```

Below is the RaisedButton that when pressed, should trigger the process of checking the pin:

```
                                    Padding(
                                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
                                      child: Material(
                                          child: RaisedButton(
                                              textColor: Colors.white,
                                              color: Colors.blue,
                                              child: Text(
                                                  "Company Log In"),
                                              onPressed: () async {
                                                String newPin =
                                                    await getCompanyPin(
                                                        _selectedCompany);


                                                if (_logFormKey
                                                    .currentState
                                                    .validate()) {
                                                  _logFormKey
                                                      .currentState
                                                      .save();

                                                      checkPin(newPin, _pin);
                                                }
                                              })),
                                    )
```

Comment: I can not see any question in your post. Could you explain a little more what is the problem? Thanks!

Comment: When I press the raised button to trigger the checking of the new pin nothing happens

Comment: In the getCompanyPin method you use await and then int he same Future, maybe the problem is there.